# HttpwebRequest Crashes without exception when hiting a mobile url

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, web-scraping

I am hitting a url as sample below:

```
http://mobile.example.com/ip/someProduct-fl-oz/productID
```

And my Request is :

```
    public static string getMobileHtml(string url)
    {
        string responseData = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
            request.Timeout = 10000;
            request.Host = "mobile.example.com";
            request.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

And the code crashes on line:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

Without any exception just breaks off, same thing was happening in `Curl Lib`,`WebClient` but i changed it to `HttpWebRequest` assuming it would be a fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: does your url start with "http" ? I also recommend that you read about the "request.host" property here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx

Comment: @MauricioGracia yes the same url entered in Ie,FireFox and i replicated this above request using Fiddler so it's all that make it works. It does not even reach the host part as i said it crashed on top.

Comment: if you use "WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);" still fails ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia let me try...

Comment: @MauricioGracia hey it works with WebResponse and WebRequest But still i cannot get the html it closes before returning any thing why is that?

Comment: @MauricioGracia also its not consistent now its crashing on webresponse line ....i need something perfect as i will be running many urls.

Comment: ConfusedMind I tested your posted code ahd the HttpWebRequest was created succesfully, it then failed at the response line, but in my case is because I am behind a firewall and I did not provided any credentials

Comment: @MauricioGracia wierd its not running on my end...

Comment: @MauricioGracia it never happend to me before but when i closed fiddler it works :| /

Comment: confusedMind maybe fiddler some how kept a request open

Comment: thanx for your help will close this q now.

Comment: confusedMind instead of closing please mark as answer my new post

Comment: Not sure  why  i get -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your posted code ahd the HttpWebRequest was created succesfully, it then failed at the response line, but in my case is because I am behind a firewall and I did not provided any credentials.

The problem was diagnosed as Fiddler affecting your tests, so closing it solve the problem